# Finding the pdf of particular element.

Tags: probability-distributions

> Let $Y_2$ denote the second smallest item of a random sample of size $n$ from a 
>   distribution of the continuous type that  has  $\text{cdf }F(x)$ and $\text{pdf }f(x) = F'(x)$. Find the limiting distribution of $Wn =  nF(Y_2)$.

I am not sure where to start.

Comment: $Pr[W_n\le w]=Pr[F(Y_2)\le\frac{w}{n}]=Pr[Y_2\le F^{-1}(\frac{w}{n})]$. Now $Y_2$ is sometimes called an ordinal statistic and IIRC you can use a binomial argument to calculate this probability: how many ways of choosing one of $n$ of the $X_i$ (if $Y_2$ is the second smallest of $\{X_1,\dots,X_n\}$) to be less than $Y_2$... [Ross](http://books.google.ch/books/about/A_first_course_in_probability.html?id=Bc1FAQAAIAAJ&redir_esc=y) has a good treatment of it.

Comment: @bgins Isn't $W_n=nF(Y_2)$? In which case, your first equality is a bit off?

Comment: @KannappanSampath: thank you, just in time!

Answer (score 3):

For a distribution of continuous type, we can neglect the possibility that two of the samples are equal, since this has probability $0$. Thus the probability density for the second smallest item being $y_2$ is the probability of getting one sample below $y_2$ times the probability density at $y_2$ times the probability of getting $n-2$ samples above $y_2$, times a factor accounting for the permutations. All $(n-2)!$ permutations of the $n-2$ samples are already being counted, so we just have to account for the $n(n-1)$ ordered choices of the smallest and second smallest item. Thus the probability density is

$$n(n-1)F(y_2)f(y_2)(1-F(y_2))^{n-2}\;.$$

We can integrate this to get rid of the derivative $f=F'$:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
P(Y_2\gt y_2)
&=&
\int_{y_2}^\infty n(n-1)F(y)f(y)(1-F(y))^{n-2}\mathrm dy
\\
&=&
\int_{y_2}^\infty n(n-1)F(y)(1-F(y))^{n-2}\frac{\mathrm dF(y)}{\mathrm dy}\mathrm dy
\\
&=&
\int_{F(y_2)}^1n(n-1)F(1-F)^{n-2}\mathrm dF
\\
&=&
\int_0^{1-F(y_2)}n(n-1)(1-u)u^{n-2}\mathrm du
\\
&=&
n(1-F(y_2))^{n-1}-(n-1)(1-F(y_2))^n\;.
\end{eqnarray}
$$

With $W_n=nF(Y_2)$, this becomes

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
P(W_n\gt w)
&=&
n\left(1-\frac wn\right)^{n-1}-(n-1)\left(1-\frac wn\right)^n
\\
&=&
\left(1-\frac wn\right)^{n-1}\left(n-(n-1)\left(1-\frac wn\right)\right)
\\
&=&
\left(1-\frac wn\right)^{n-1}\left(1+w-\frac wn\right)\;.
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Thus the limit distribution is

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}P(W_n\gt w)=(1+w)\mathrm e^{-w}\;,
$$

or

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}P(W_n\lt w)=1-(1+w)\mathrm e^{-w}=\frac12w^2+O\left(w^3\right)\;.
$$

[Here's a plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%201-%281%2bw%29e%5E%28-w%29%20for%20w=0..5).

Comment: Why do you multiply by the probability density of y2?

Comment: @lord12: You can use $\TeX$ on this site. Inline formulas are enclosed in single dollar signs, displayed equations in double dollar signs. Patrick formatted your question for you. If you don't know the $\TeX$ commands for something you see on the site, you can right-click on it and select "Show Math As ... TeX commands". For instance, the code for $y_2$ is `y_2`.

Comment: $ F_W(w)=1-(1+w)e^{-w} \Rightarrow f_W(w)=\frac{d}{dw}F_W(w)=we^{-w},w>0. $ That is $ W\sim\mathrm{Gam}(\alpha=2,\beta=1). $